# To what extent are LDAP distinguished names sustainable?

Tags: ldap

I just learned that in LDAP, distinguished names (DNs) are made up of relative distinguished
names (RDNs), and that an RDN can be any set of attribute/value pairs associated with a
directory entry, as long as the resulting DN is uniquely identifying that entry within the
parent entry.

Does this mean that it could happen over time, when other entries are added, that what once was a valid DN, no
longer is valid anymore (i.e. no longer uniquely identifying)?

If yes, are there rules or guidelines as to what should be uniquely identifying attributes
of an entry within a parent entry, to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as long as the resulting DN is uniquely identifying that entry within the parent entry.

Within the DIT. The RDN has to be unique within the parent, the DN within the entire DIT.

> Does this mean that it could happen over time, when other entries are added, that what once was a valid DN, no longer is valid anymore (i.e. no longer uniquely identifying)?

No, because you will not be permitted to add a DN that already exists, or rename an entry to an existing DN of another entry.

That's why it's called 'DN'. Distinguished Name. It is distinguished from all other names, and therefore distinct.

Comment: Do you mean that the DN for an entry is fixed at creation time?

Comment: No, but when you add it it has to be unique, and if you rename it ditto. There is no way it can become non-unique.

Comment: I mean, at a certain point in time, an entry has only one DN? Not multiple possible DNs?

Comment: It has one DN but any number of aliases and referrals can point to it. I don't see how that bears on your original question.

Comment: I thought that at any point in time, any arbitrary set of attributes could be used to make up a RDN. But apparently that is not true. There is just a single RDN, and aliases have to be made explicitly.

Comment: Both statements are true. Any arbitrary set of attributes can be used to make up *the* RDN, and *the* RDN is unique within the parent. For example I am using `cn=xxx+mail=yyy`. Again, this is what RDN means: Relative Distinguished Name. It is unique relative to the parent.

Comment: Yes, so it is not true that all possible aliases can be used implicitly, when querying for the entry.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about now. You can use any alias that points to the entry.

Comment: Not if the alias is not created in the ldap database.

Comment: Your last two comments are mere nonsense. An alias that doesn't exist in the database isn't an alias at all. It is nothing, and doesn't point to anything either. I can try to answer sensible questions, but nobody can answer meaningless ones.

Comment: "An alias that doesn't exist in the database isn't an alias at all. It is nothing" Well there you have it. That is a technical assumption. And me being an ldap noob did not know this.

Comment: It isn't a 'technical assumption'. It is a logical fact. A thing that doesn't exist doesn't exist. QED. You aren't making any sense whatsoever. 'So it is not true that all possible aliases can be used implicitly' is meaningless, as 'possible alias' can only mean an alias that refers to something, and so is 'not if the alias is not created in the ldap database', as there is no such thing as an alias that isn't 'created in the LDAP database'. And none of this has anything to do with your original question whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for trying to understand my question. And my apologies for not being able to clearly state my question. If you don't understand how something works and/or have misunderstandings about it, it can be hard to formulate what you don't understand.

Comment: To the extent that I answered your original question, you should consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer. I really cannot understand most of the subsequent discussion, and specifically what on earth an 'alias that doesn't exist in the database' could possibly mean. There are no aliases *other* than those that exist in the database.